# Dynamic DNS Name to resolve to Internal Server IP Address

Tags: networking, dns

I need to setup a DNS route so that the Dynamic DNS Name resolves to the Server when users are connected on the same network as the server, when users use any other internet connection the Dynamic DNS name needs to resolve to the public IP of the router. Example:

Pinging test.ddns.net on the internal network needs to resolve to 10.0.0.1 and when outside the network or when using 3G connectiontion when pinging test.ddns.net needs to resolve to public ip 105.158.142.121

Server 2012 R2 Standard installed with IPCOP 1.4.21 as the Firewall.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your internal DNS Server and add a new zone ddns.net and then add an A entry test with the ip 10.0.0.1 .

Be aware that this will have side effects like you dns server will not be able resolve any other ddns.net addresses.